# Is $g\mid f$ and $ord(f)=ord(g)$ implies that the splitting field of $f$ equals that of $g$?

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

Question:

> Let $f,g$ be two polynomials over Finite field $F$ such that $g\mid f$
>   and $ord(f)=ord(g)$. If $f$ is square-free and $f(0)\ne 0$, can we say that  the splitting field of $f$ equals that of $g$ ? If it is true, show it.

Let $f$ be a polynomial over Finite field $F$. The order of $f$, denoted by $ord(f)$, is defined by the least positive integer $e$ such that $f \mid x^e-1$.

> Lemma 1:Let $f=\prod_{i=1}^{k}{f_i^{e_i}}$ be a polynomial over Finite
>   field $F$, where $f_i$ are irreducible and $e_i$ are positive
>   integers. Let $p$ be the characteristic of $F$. Then $ord(f)=p^t
> > lcm(r_1,\ldots,r_k)$, where $r_i=ord(f_i)$ and $t$ is the least
>   positive integer such that $p^t\ge \max(e_1,\ldots,e_k)$.

Thanks for the answer posted by [Lord Shark the Unknown](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/436618/lord-shark-the-unknown). The conclusion is as follows.

> Let $f, g$ be two square-free polynomials over finite field
>   $\mathbb{F}_q$. Then the splitting field of $f$ is that of $g$, up to
>   isomorphism, if and only if $\text{ord}(f)=\text{ord}(g)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\text{ord}(f)=d$. Then every root of $f(x)=0$ is a $d$-th root of unity and so the splitting field of $f$ is contained in the cyclotomic
extension $F(\mu_d)$. Here $\mu_d$ is the group of $d$-th
roots of unity in an algebraic closure of $f$. But also $d$ is
the least common multiple of the orders of the zeros of $f$. Thus
$d$ is the order of the multiplicative group generated by the zeros of $f$.
Thus $\mu_d$ is contained in the splitting field of $f$. We conclude that
$F(\mu_d)$ is the splitting field of $f$, that is $\text{ord}(f)$ determines
the splitting field.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's greate that splitting field of $f$ is determined by $\text{ord}(f)$. Let $f, g$ be two polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_q$. Then  $SpliitingField(f)=SplittingField(g)$ if and only if $\text{ord}(f)=\text{ord}(g)$. Am I right?

Comment: Why do you delete comment "That's it. -- as long as $f$,$g$ are square-free." ? Is there something more needed to be considered ?